# Symfony2, One form to edit and create User

Tags: forms, symfony

I need a form that create User and add a ROLE to them. The form work but now, if i enter an email that already exist, i want "edit" the user instead of "create" it.

How can i "bypass" one constraint (email uniqueness) ?

In my controller:

```
        $form = $this->createForm(new TheFormType(), $user);
```

TheFormType:

```
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
       $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Project\WebBundle\Entity\User\User',
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ));
    }
```

When i use:

```
 $this->form->handleRequest($this->request);
```

I don't want him to check the email constraint but i want it to check others constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You can use validation groups. Add group to user email field:

```
/**
* @Assert\Email(groups={"registration"})
*/
private $email;
```

And then in controller action you can use validator service and `validate()` method. Datails in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using FOSuserbundle the route to edit your profile is `/profile/edit`. You should override the edit form from FOSuserBundle like pasting one file in: `app/Resources/FOSuserBundle/Form/Type`
I believe this file: 
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Form/Type/ProfileFormType.php

And removing this line to not show the email.

```
    ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
```

However I cannot override FOSuserBundle things since a while. So I cannot say if that would work.

Also you could autogenerate crud controllers for the entity user,

```
 php app/console generate:doctrine:crud
```

then the route for edit some profile will be /users/{id}/edit you could add a verification to check if the current user editing has the same id or if admin and if not send a 503 error or something.

The auto generation of crud controllers will generate something like this:

I added the          `$form->remove("email");`

wich remove the email field in the edit page.

```
/**
* Creates a form to edit a User entity.
*
* @param User $entity The entity
*
* @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
*/
private function createEditForm(User $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('usuarios_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));


    $form->remove("email");


    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('attr'=> array('class'=>'update_submit' ), 'label' => 'Update'));
    return $form;
}
```

You are using a TheFormType class, I guess that is a entire form and you render the same form in /new and /edit. You could try to do in the controller of /edit

```
$form = TheFormType();
$form -> remove(emailFieldName);
```

But not sure if this would work.

Offtopic: So hard to write solution in this tiny(horizontal no resizable) box with that crappy markup. I don't understand how this site is "so" sucessful.